# Why do I get [object Object] instead of the object property value?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an unordered list of food items that show once I click a button. I am trying to display the name of each item only. However instead of showing the item names, I am getting an unordered list with each item displaying [object Object].

[image of four bullet points stating object Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDE07.png)

How can I display the list item names in my list instead of [object Object]?

```
let groceryList = [
{name: "banana", price: 5},
{name: "milk", price: 3},
{name: "bread", price: 1},
{name: "chips", price: 2}
]

let ul = document.getElementById("itemList")
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
     for (let i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++) {
         let item = groceryList[i]
         let li = document.createElement("li")
         li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item))
         ul.appendChild(li)
     }
        
 })
```

Comment: because you are stroing an object into a string and it runs toString(). You need to reference the properties of the object to get the text `.createTextNode(item.name)`

Comment: The object is managed in memory, so its native representation is `[object Object]`. You may want to stringify it: `li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(item)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you say:

```
let item = groceryList[i]
```

That returns an object and thus displays as `[object Object]`. You can access the properties of this object with `groceryList[i].name` and `groceryList[i].price`; that will return a string or number respectively.

Comment: you are a lifesaver!! this was so useful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`let item = groceryList[i]` return whole object, if you want to access the value of `name` or `price`, you should access it by using key of that value.

```js
let groceryList = [
{name: "banana", price: 5},
{name: "milk", price: 3},
{name: "bread", price: 1},
{name: "chips", price: 2}
]


 
 groceryList.forEach(item => {
  console.log("item", item)
  //To access the name
  console.log("name", item.name)
  //To access the price
  console.log("price", item.price)
 })
```